# Experiment shows that LSTM does worse than Random Forest... Why?

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, random-forest

LSTM is supposed to be the right tool to capture path-dependency in time-series data.

I decided to run a simple experiment (simulation) to assess the extent to which LSTM is better able to *understand* path-dependency.

The setting is very simple. I just simulate a bunch (N=100) of paths coming from 4 different data generating processes. Two of these processes represent a *real* increase and a *real* decrease, while the other two *fake* trends that eventually revert to zero.

The following plot shows the simulated paths for each category:

[image: Simulated paths]

The candidate machine learning algorithm will be given the first 8 values of the path ( t in [1,8] ) and will be trained to predict the subsequent movement over the last 2 steps.

In other words:

- the feature vector is `X = (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8)`
- the target is `y = p10 - p8`

I compared LSTM with a simple Random Forest model with 20 estimators. Here are the definitions and the training of the two models, using Keras and scikit-learn:

```
# LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM((1), batch_input_shape=(None, H, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM((1), return_sequences=False))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_X_LS, train_y_LS, epochs=100, validation_data=(vali_X_LS, vali_y_LS), verbose=0)
```

```
# Random Forest
RF = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0, n_estimators=20)
RF.fit(train_X_RF, train_y_RF);
```

The out-of-sample results are the summarized by the following scatter plots:

[image]

As you can see, the Random Forest model is clearly outperforming the LSTM. The latter seems to be not able to distinguish between the *real* and the *fake* trends.

#### Do you have any idea to explain why this is happening?

#### How would you modify the LSTM model to make it better at this problem?

Some remarks:

- The data points are divided by 100 to make sure gradients do not explode
- I tried to increase the sample size, but I noticed no differences
- I tried to increase the number of epochs over which the LSTM is trained, but I noticed no differences (the loss becomes stagnant after a bunch of epochs)
- You can find the code I used to run the experiment [here](https://pastebin.com/QL2DuKDE)

## Update:

Thanks to `SaTa`'s reply, I changed the model and obtained much better results:

```
# Updated LSTM Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM((8), batch_input_shape=(None, H, 1), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image: Better Results]

Still, the Random Forest model does better. The point is that RF seems to `understand` that, conditional on the class, a higher `p8` predicts a lower outcome `p10-p8` and viceversa because of the way the noise is added. LSTM seems to fail on that, so it predicts the class rather well, but we see that within-class downward-sloping pattern in the final scatter plot.

**Any suggestion to improve on that?**

Comment: How many samples are you using for training? Are the results shown training or test results?

Comment: @SaTa: I'm using N=100 data samples. I tried to augment it to 1,000 and 10,000 but the results are the same. The results are out-of-sample on the test set, but they look the same in-sample since the data is simulated in a homogeneous way

Answer (score 1):

I won't expect LSTM to win at all the battles against traditional methods, but I do expect it to perform well for the problem you have posed. Here are couple things you can try:

1) Increase the number of hidden units in the first layer.

```
model.add(LSTM((32), batch_input_shape=(None, H, 1), return_sequences=True))
```

2) The output of an LSTM layer is tanh by default which limits the output to (-1, 1) as you can see in the right plot. I recommend either adding a Dense layer or using LSTM with linear activation on the output. Like this:

```
model.add(LSTM((1), return_sequences=False, activation='linear'))
```

Or

```
model.add(LSTM((16), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Try the above with 10K samples that you have.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I updated the simulation and got much better results (see the update)

Comment: Cool. What are your training and test errors? Have you tried to make it slightly bigger with more hidden unites until it starts to overfit?

Comment: And maybe replace the middle Dense layer with an LSTM layer so that you have two stacked LSTM layers and a final Dense layer. See if that helps.